# Swift Url Bookmark Permissions Lost After Computer Restart

Tags: swift, macos

I am working on a macOS music app, where I prompt user to select a library directory. After selection, directory is scanned, and music objects are created in Core Data. In order to retain the permissions to directory and urls of its content, I store directory url as a bookmark. Simplified code:

```
let directoryAndPermissionsKey: String = "" // Key for storing url to UserDefaults


/// Saves directory and permissions
func storeDirectoryAndPermissions(for directory: URL) throws -> Void {
    // Saves directory and permissions
    do {
        // Creates bookmark
        let bookmark: Data = try directory.bookmarkData(options: .securityScopeAllowOnlyReadAccess, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)

        // Stores directory and permissions
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: directoryAndPermissionsKey)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(bookmark, forKey: directoryAndPermissionsKey)

    // Throws error
    } catch {
        throw PersistentLibraryError.cannotSaveDirectory
    }
}


/// Retrieves directory
func retrieveDirectoryUrl() -> URL? {
    // Indicates if data is stale
    var isStale: Bool = false

    // Makes sure that directory and permissions are stored
    guard
        UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: directoryAndPermissionsKey) != nil,
        let bookmarkData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: directoryAndPermissionsKey) as? Data,
        let directory = try? URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
    else {
        return nil
    }

    // Starts accessing directory
    _ = directory.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() 

    // Returns directory
    return directory
}
```

Also, in plist file, I have the following lines included:

```
<key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-only</key>
<true/>
<key>com.apple.security.files.bookmarks.app-scope</key>
<true/>
```

Code has been working perfectly up until now. Even when I close and re-launch the app, I still can initialize AV Audio Player without any permission issues.

However, I have recently found out, that when I restart the computer, following error is thrown when attempting to initialize AVAudioPlayer:

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-54 "permErr: permissions error (on file open)"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems that you're not handling `isStale == true`. When it fails, is `isStale` `true`?

Comment: Also I think that you have to combine `.securityScopeAllowOnlyReadAccess` with `.withSecurityScope`.

Comment: No, I just checked. When I add new directory and permissions are granted, ```false``` is returned. I restarted computer, and still ```false``` was returned, but now, without being able to initialize AV Audio Player.

Comment: ```.withSecurityScope``` actually broke the permissions after re-launching the app, let alone restarting the computer

Comment: One more thing I just noticed - you're not passing `.withSecurityScope` when resolving bookmark (`URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, options: [.withSecurityScope], ...)`).

Comment: Oh god yes. After restarting computer, permissions work. I have made the following changes as you suggested. You can make a new comment with these changes and I will mark it as a correct answer. ```let bookmark: Data = try directory.bookmarkData(options: .withSecurityScope, includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)``` and ```let directory = try? URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, options: [.withSecurityScope], relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)```. Thanks again.

Comment: It's just weird how restarting the computer was breaking it, and not logging out of the user, or re-launching the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Create a bookmark

[`securityScopeAllowOnlyReadAccess`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfurlbookmarkcreationoptions/1543362-securityscopeallowonlyreadaccess]) documentation:

> When combined with the `withSecurityScope` option ...

It should be combined with the `withSecurityScope`, that's what you're missing.

```swift
let bookmark: Data = try directory.bookmarkData(options: [.withSecurityScope, .securityScopeAllowOnlyReadAccess], includingResourceValuesForKeys: nil, relativeTo: nil)
```

### Resolve a bookmark

[`init(resolvingBookmarkData:options:relativeTo:bookmarkDataIsStale:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3126805-init) documentation:

> To resolve a security-scoped bookmark to support App Sandbox, include the `withSecurityScope` option.

That's the 2nd thing you're missing when resolving a bookmark.

```swift
let directory = try? URL(resolvingBookmarkData: bookmarkData, options: [.withSecurityScope], relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &isStale)
```

---

While this should fix your issue, be aware that you're not handling `isStale`. You have to update your bookmark data if it's `true`.